# what is exactly the halting in turing machines ?

Tags: computation-theory, turing-machines, decidable

I am new to decidability. I read halting problem of halting problem but didn't get anything what it is actually implying. I am already screwed up with the explaination.

Can anyone provide me any sound explaination or atleast some details, it would be of much help ?

Answer (score 3):

You can think of a Turing machine as a sort of theoretical computer that can execute programs. A program for a Turing machine consists of a set of states and transitions between these states. Programs running on Turing machines have access to a single input source, called the tape, which has some string (possibly empty) the program can process. All programs for Turing machines either `return true` (halt-accept), `return false` (halt-reject), or fail to ever `return` anything at all - `while (true) ; return true;`. Depending on your definition it may also be possible for the machine to `throw` an exception (crash); but typically crashing is thought of as something like `try { /*crash*/ } catch (Exception) { return false; }` so that crashing means halt-reject.

The halting problem, then, is whether you can write a program for a Turing machine, whose input is another program for a Turing machine and some string of input, which returns `true` or `false` (halt-accepts or halt-rejects) if the program it has been given halts on the input provided and returns `false` otherwise (i.e., if the program never halts).

It turns out the answer is that no such general program exists for Turing machines. Suppose one did exist, `M`. Given inputs `m` and `i` it accepts if `m` halts on `i` and rejects otherwise. We can make another program specifically designed to fool `M`:

```
N(i)
1. if M(N, i) then loop forever;
2. otherwise return true
```

Now continue whether `M` works on `N`:

1. Suppose `M` says that `N` halts on input `i`. Then `N` will loop forever, and `M` will have been wrong.
2. Suppose `M` says that `N` loops forever on input `i`. Then `N` will return true and halt, so `M` will have been wrong.

In either case, `M` comes up with the wrong answer for our `N`, and since we made no assumptions about `M` other than that it exists and solves the halting problem, we may safely conclude that no machine that solves the halting problem exists.

(`M` may be passed into the program `N` as input if it is preferred not to reference `M` directly).